# Powershell, Excel Finding string in cell, Color row, delete others

Tags: excel, powershell

I am looking for a way to read my excel sheet, then;

1. Find empty cells and give them a name, then mark them yellow.
2. Find rows containing a certain set of word and mark it red. If the script
3. If cannot find the words specified in row it should delete the entire row.

*Here's my script so far:*
*Any help will be much appreciated*

Updated with help of @TheMadTechician

```
#If there is no Out-Clipboard, set it
If(!(Get-Command Out-Clipboard -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)){Set-Alias Out-Clipboard "$env:SYSTEMROOT\System32\clip.exe"}

#Get current date
$Date = get-date -format yyyy-MM-dd
$Company = "company"
$Company2 = "company2"
#Define all files/Paths.
$Path = "C:\$Company2\BlockedIP"
md "$Path\HTML\$Date" -Force |Out-Null
$path2 = "$Path\HTML\$Date"
$PathWeb = "/HTML/$Date"

#Path = C:/$Company2/BlockedIP
#Path2 = C:/$Company2/BlockedIP/HTML/2014-07-09

#Define File's used or created in this script.
$File = "$Path\IP-$Date.txt"
$FileHtml = "$Path2\IP-$Date.htm"
$FileXML = "$Path\IP-$Date.xlsx"
$FileHTMLWeb = "$PathWeb\IP-$date.htm"

#File = C:/$Company2/BlockedIP/IP-2014-07-09.txt
#FileXML = C:/$Company2/BlockedIP/HTML/2014-07-09/IP-2014-07-09.htm
#FileHtml = C:/$Company2/BlockedIP/HTML/2014-07-09/IP-2014-07-09.xlsx
#FileHTMLWeb = PublicIP/HTML/2014-07-09/IP-2014-07-09.htm



#Define error actions.
#$erroractionpreference = "SilentlyContinue"

#Get content from given IP list.
$colComputers = @(get-content $File | Sort -unique)
$count = $colComputers.Count
    write-output "$Count IP's detected."

#Get DNS Results
$Progress=1
$DNSResults = $colComputers | %{
 Write-Progress -Activity "Creating a usable 'Blocked IP' list ($Progress/$count)" -PercentComplete ($Progress/$Count*100) -Status "Please stand by"
try {
    ($dnsresult = [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry($_))|out-null
}
catch {
    $dnsresult = "Fail"
}
[PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
    Source=$_.ToUpper()
    HostName=$dnsresult.HostName
    IPAddress=$dnsresult.AddressList[0].ToString()
}
$Progress++
}

$DNSResults | Sort HostName | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation | Select -Skip 1 | Out-Clipboard

#Open Excel.
$a = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application

#Since we want this script to look like it's being used without excel I set it's visibility to false.
$a.visible = $True

#Disable excel confirmations.
$a.DisplayAlerts = $False

<# 
# set interactive to false so nothing from excel is shown.
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$Excel.ScreenUpdating = $false
$Excel.Visible = $false
$Excel.UserControl = $false
$Excel.Interactive = $false
#>

#Create sheets in Excel.
$b = $a.Workbooks.Add()
$c = $b.Worksheets.Item(1)
$c.Activate() | Out-Null

#Create a Title for the first worksheet and adjust the font
$c.Cells.Item(1,1)= "Blocked IP's $Date"
$c.Cells.Item(1,1).Font.ColorIndex = 55
$c.Cells.Item(1,1).Font.Color = 8210719
$range = $c.Range("a1","e1")
$range.Style = 'Title'
$range.Select()
$range.MergeCells = $true
$range.VerticalAlignment = -4108

$CounterRow = $Count+5
#Define subjects.
$c.Name = "Blocked IP's ($Date)"
$c.Cells.Item(2,1) = "Given IP"
$c.Cells.Item(2,2) = "Resolved DNS"
$c.Cells.Item(2,3) = "Returned IP"
$c.Cells.Item(2,5) = "$Company"
$c.Cells.Item($Count+5,1) = "Created by"
$link = "http://www.$Company"
$link2 = "https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=#########"
$r = $c.Range("E2") 
[void]$c.Hyperlinks.Add($r, $link) 
$r = $c.Range("A$Counterrow") 
[void]$c.Hyperlinks.Add($r, $link)

#Define cell formatting from subjects.
$c.Range("A2:E2").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
$c.Range("A2:E2").font.size = 13
$c.Range("A2:E2").Font.ColorIndex = 1
$c.Range("A2:E2").Font.Bold = $True

#Define html code for Excel save to .htm.
$xlExcelHTML = 44

#Define the usedrange, excluding header and footer rows
$e = $c.Range("A3:E$($DNSResults.Count+2)")

#Populate data into spreadsheet
$DNSResults | Sort HostName | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation | Select -Skip 1 | Out-Clipboard
#$c.Cells.Item(3,1).Select()
$c.Paste($e,$false)

$e = $c.Range("A3:C$($DNSResults.Count+2)")
$c.Paste($e,$false)

$Keywords = "Google","thenetworkfactory","HappyTreeFriends"
$Filter = "($(($Keywords|%{[RegEx]::Escape($_)}) -join "|"))"

$DNSResults | Where{$_ -match $filter} | Sort HostName | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation | Select -Skip 1 | Out-Clipboard


ForEach($Cell in $e){
If([String]::IsNullOrWhitespace($Cell.value2)){$Cell.interior.colorindex=6}
}

#Define the usedrange for autofitting.
$d = $c.UsedRange

#Set background color for the IP list.
$E.interior.colorindex = 15

#Define borders here.
$xlOpenXMLWorkbook = 51
$xlAutomatic=-4105
$xlBottom = -4107
$xlCenter = -4108
$xlRight = -4152
$xlContext = -5002
$xlContinuous=1
$xlDiagonalDown=5
$xlDiagonalUp=6
$xlEdgeBottom=9
$xlEdgeLeft=7
$xlEdgeRight=10
$xlEdgeTop=8
$xlInsideHorizontal=12
$xlInsideVertical=11
$xlNone=-4142
$xlThin=2 
$selection = $c.range("A3:C$($DNSResults.Count+2)")
$selection.select() |out-null
$selection.HorizontalAlignment = $xlRight
$selection.VerticalAlignment = $xlBottom
$selection.WrapText = $false
$selection.Orientation = 0
$selection.AddIndent = $false
$selection.IndentLevel = 0
$selection.ShrinkToFit = $false
$selection.ReadingOrder = $xlContext
$selection.MergeCells = $false
$selection.Borders.Item($xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = $xlThin



#Make everything fit in it's cell.
$d.EntireColumn.AutoFit() | Out-Null

#Save the file as .xlsx on every placed IP to ensure the file is not lost due to any reason.
$b.SaveAs("$FileXML")

#Clear screen on every checked IP to remove the 'True' statement.
#cls
#


#Save final result as a .htm file
$b.SaveAs("$FileHTML",$xlExcelHTML)

#Close and quit Excel.
$b.Close()
get-process *Excel* | Stop-Process -force

#Move .txt file to the correct HTML folder.
move-item $file $path2 -Force

#Move .xlsx file to the correct HTML folder.
move-item $filexml $path2 -Force

#Declare XLSX file for mail
$MailXML = "$path2\IP-$Date.xlsx"

#Clear screen, again. (Let's keep things tidy.)
#cls

#Variables for public IP
# I am defining website url in a variable
$url = "http://checkip.dyndns.com" 
# Creating a new .Net Object names a System.Net.Webclient
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
# In this new webdownlader object we are telling $webclient to download the
# url $url 
$IpPublic = $webclient.DownloadString($url)
# Just a simple text manuplation to get the ipadress form downloaded URL
# If you want to know what it contain try to see the variable $IpPublic
$IpPublic2 = $IpPublic.ToString()
$ipPublic3 = $IpPublic2.Split(" ")
$ipPublic4 = $ipPublic3[5]
$ipPublic5 = $ipPublic4.replace("</body>","")
$FinalIPAddress = $ipPublic5.replace("</html>","")
$ipLocal = (Get-WmiObject -class win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter 'ipenabled = "true"').ipaddress[0]

#Variables e-mail.
$From = "Blocked IP <r.van.tour@$Company>"
$To = "IT Dept <r.van.tour@$Company>"
$CC = "Someone <$Company2@$Company"
$Subject = "Blocked IPs for $date ($Count Total)"
#The href should point to the htm file in your iis/apache folder.
$WebLink = $FinalIPAddress+$FileHtmlWeb
$here = "<a href='http://$Weblink'><b>Here</b></a>"
#Define the body of your e-mail, in this case it displays a message and shows the server it is send from with it's local IP.
#A link to the .htm file, how many IP's were blocked and the date of the message.
$Body = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head> <title>Blocked IP's $Date</title></head><header><h1>Blocked IP</h1><p><time pubdate datetime='$date'></time></p></header><br>" 
$body += "<body>Dear <font color=black>$to</font>,<br><br>"
$body += "This is an automated message generated by server: <font color=red><b>$env:COMPUTERNAME, $IPLocal.</b></font><br><br>"
$body += "Click <font color=red><b>$here</b></font> to see the Blocked IP report for $date containing $count IP's.<br>"
$body += "Or see the attachment to open it in Excel.<br></body></html>"


#Clear screen, again. (Let's keep things tidy.)
#cls

#Send output as e-mail.
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
$Username = "##@gmail.com"
$Password = "##"
$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$message.IsBodyHTML = $true
$message.ReplyTo = $From
$message.Sender = $From
$message.subject = $subject
$message.body = $body
$message.to.add($to)
$message.from = $From
$message.attachments.add($MailXML)
$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);
$smtp.EnableSSL = $true
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
$smtp.send($message)

#Create a function to relase Com object at end of script.
function Release-Ref ($ref) { 
([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject( 
[System.__ComObject]$ref) -gt 0) 
[System.GC]::Collect() 
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers() 
                        }

#Release COM Object
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$a) | Out-Null

#Clear screen for the final time. (Let's keep things tidy.)
#cls

#Exit powershell 
exit
```

@TheMadTechnician

There seems to be a problem with this part of the script where non-resolved IP adresses fail to be shown in $DNSResults

```
$Keywords = "Google","Cloudflare","Cloud","Ping","Easy-    Voyage","McAfee","Pingdom","Panopta","Scoot","Uniglobe"
$Filter = "($(($Keywords|%{[RegEx]::Escape($_)}) -join "|"))"

#Define error actions.
#$erroractionpreference = "SilentlyContinue"

#Get content from given IP list.
$colComputers = @(get-content $File | Sort -unique)
$SourceCount = $colComputers.Count
write-output "$SourceCount IP's detected."

#Get DNS Results
$Progress=1
$DNSResults = $colComputers | %{
Write-Progress -Activity "Creating a usable 'Blocked IP' list ($Progress/$sourcecount)" -PercentComplete ($Progress/$sourceCount*100) -Status "Please stand by"
try {
    ($dnsresult = [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry($_))|out-null
}
catch {
    $dnsresult = "Fail"
}
[PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
    Source=$_.ToUpper()
    HostName=$dnsresult.HostName
    IPAddress=$dnsresult.AddressList[0].ToString()
}
$Progress++
}

$count = ($DNSResults|?{$_ -match $filter}).count
```

Comment: I'm looking at the rest of it, but as far as your progress bar goes move `$i=1` above `ForEach($strComputer in $colComputers)` and add `$i++` after `$intRow = $intRow + 1` (which could be shortened to `$intRow++`)

Comment: Ok, I have notes on your code in general, and I think we can do what you want, but I'm going home to celebrate my step daughter's birthday so my answer will have to wait until tomorrow. I should get something posted for you in the morning though, I've already got it partially worked out.

Comment: I haven't forgotten, but I didn't feel right just posting a short answer even if it was functional. There's some good chances for learning so my post is coming but just isn't done yet due to some re-working of your script.

Comment: Why did someone downvote this, I spend a lot of time on this, also the awnser from madtechnician was downvoted... strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I'm guessing you have borrowed and pieced this together from scripts found all over because the way it is put together seems kind of unplanned. Like things were added and revised, and there wasn't a master plan that put it all together. So, where to start? With the progress bar, since I already addressed that.

## The Progress Bar

Move `$i=1` above `ForEach($strComputer in $colComputers)` and add `$i++` after `$intRow = $intRow + 1` (which could be shortened to `$intRow++`). But we already knew that. This kind of becomes a moot point, since I've reworked a good bit of your script, but in practice you'll see it with the ForEach loop coming up next.

## The ForEach Loop

Next, your ForEach loop. Boy, that's quite a doozy there. You are making it do things over, and over, and over that really just need to be done once after everything is complete. So, what shall we move to after the loop? Let's start with, well, almost everything. Cell formatting? Later. Filling cells? Later. Sorting? Later. Adjusting column width? Later. Saving the file? Later!

So, what does that leave us in the loop? Not much really, all it leaves is the progress bar and checking DNS entries. Why do it this way? Because we can create an array in PowerShell with the data you want, sort the data, select only the fields that you want to use from the array, and then paste all data in at once instead of one record at a time, and do all the formatting afterwards. In fact, what would probably be better for formatting, instead of checking cells for blanks and coloring them red is to just apply Conditional Formatting to them so that if they're blank they show up red, and let Excel do the work for you.

This is going to make the script run a lot faster since you aren't doing the same work several times, and are working with raw data in PowerShell instead of making Excel do it. I ended up reducing your ForEach loop down to just a few lines:

```
#Get DNS Results
$Progress=1
$DNSResults = $colComputers | %{
     Write-Progress -Activity "Creating a usable 'Blocked IP' list ($Progress/$count)" -PercentComplete ($Progress/$Count*100) -Status "Please stand by"
    try {
        ($dnsresult = [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry($_))|out-null
    }
    catch {
        $dnsresult = "Fail"
    }
    [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
        Source=$_.ToUpper()
        HostName=$dnsresult.HostName
        IPAddress=$dnsresult.AddressList[0].ToString()
    }
    $Progress++
}
```

That will loop through the entries and create an array of custom objects that have 3 properties that are the 3 cells you wanted in your spreadsheet.

## Excel Setup

Ok, you obviously have a grasp of things as far as formatting and injecting simple text, so I'm going to glaze over your title setup for now and get to getting the processed data into the spreadsheet.

For arrays of data (like your Computer/HostName/IP array of data that you were putting in) it is easier to paste it into Excel as a tab delimited CSV object. Out-Clipboard isn't a standard PowerShell cmdlet, even if I think it should be. On the other hand Clip.exe comes standard with windows, so we can just set an alias for it (if you have the PowerShell Community Extensions this is already done for you). I put this at the top of the script to get it out of the way. Normally I would put it right after any functions that I had setup in a script if I needed to setup an alias like this. It checks if you have Out-Clipboard, and if you don't it sets up the alias for Clip.exe to Out-Clipboard.

```
If(!(Get-Command Out-Clipboard -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)){Set-Alias Out-Clipboard "$env:SYSTEMROOT\System32\clip.exe"}
```

Now we can pipe things to the clipboard, and that's real handy for what we want to do next. We are going to take our array and convert it to a tab delimited CSV (with no type info), skip the first entry (the header row), sort what's left by HostName, and pipe it to the clipboard.

```
$DNSResults | Sort HostName | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation | Select -Skip 1 | Out-Clipboard
```

Now we just have to paste that into Excel. To do that we need a range object to specify as the target, so I'll set that up, and then we use the WorkSheet object's Paste(Range,link) method. Don't worry about the link part, we are going to use the $false Boolean for that because we are not going to link the pasted data to a datasource for dynamic updating. This looks something like:

```
$e = $c.Range("A3:E$($DNSResults.Count+2)")
$c.Paste($e,$false)
```

Then we go on to setting the color for your results, and the rest of your formatting.

## So... why'd we change it?

So, my favorite uncle always told me growing up *"if it ain't broke, don't fix it"*. Your script did what you wanted, so why did I revamp it if it wasn't broken? The changes aren't huge, it's really about speeding things up and inserting everything at once instead of one at a time, but the biggest thing is that now we can filter in PowerShell before you insert into Excel, and that brings us to your original questions:

- Set blank cells to yellow.
- Match rows with key words, delete all other rows.

## Seek and destroy!

We'll get to the blanks in a second, but deleting the rows that don't have your certain key words is easy now. Don't delete them, just don't insert them to start with! It's easy enough to setup a list of words to filter for, and then only include records with those words when we go to export to the clipboard.

```
$Keywords = "Google","Facebook","HappyTreeFriends"
$Filter = "($(($Keywords|%{[RegEx]::Escape($_)}) -join "|"))"
```

The second line creates a string that you can do a RegEx match against. It takes your keywords, escapes any special characters, joins them up with a pipe separating them, and encloses them in parenthesis. After those two lines `$Filter = (Google|Facebook|HappyTreeFriends)`. Then on the line that you want to send data to the clipboard just add a Where clause:

```
$DNSResults | Where{$_ -match $filter} | Sort HostName | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation | Select -Skip 1 | Out-Clipboard
```

That way only records that have one of your blacklisted words will be inserted into Excel, and you don't have to worry about going back and deleting rows. You want rows that *do* have the key words to be highlighted red? Just color them that way (right now you have them set to color index 15, grey, just change that to 3 and they'll be red) to start with since they should be the only things in there.

## What's missing?

Blank cells can be hard to spot, especially once you get some formatting going, and have less defined cell borders. Finding empty cells in this case is really easy though. We already have $e, which is a range object that includes all of the data that we just inserted into Excel, even the blank cells. A range object is basically a collection of cells, each having it's own properties like it's location (row,column), formatting, value, etc. What you can do is simple enough:

```
#If there is no Out-Clipboard, set it
If(!(Get-Command Out-Clipboard -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)){Set-Alias Out-Clipboard "$env:SYSTEMROOT\System32\clip.exe"}

#Get current date
$Date = get-date -format yyyy-MM-dd
$Company = "company"
$Company2 = "company2"
#Define all files/Paths.
$Path = "C:\$Company2\BlockedIP"
md "$Path\HTML\$Date" -Force |Out-Null
$path2 = "$Path\HTML\$Date"
$PathWeb = "/HTML/$Date"

#Path = C:/$Company2/BlockedIP
#Path2 = C:/$Company2/BlockedIP/HTML/2014-07-09

#Define File's used or created in this script.
$File = "$Path\IP-$Date.txt"
$FileHtml = "$Path2\IP-$Date.htm"
$FileXML = "$Path\IP-$Date.xlsx"
$FileHTMLWeb = "$PathWeb\IP-$date.htm"

#File = C:/$Company2/BlockedIP/IP-2014-07-09.txt
#FileXML = C:/$Company2/BlockedIP/HTML/2014-07-09/IP-2014-07-09.htm
#FileHtml = C:/$Company2/BlockedIP/HTML/2014-07-09/IP-2014-07-09.xlsx
#FileHTMLWeb = PublicIP/HTML/2014-07-09/IP-2014-07-09.htm

$Keywords = "Google","thenetworkfactory"
$Filter = "($(($Keywords|%{[RegEx]::Escape($_)}) -join "|"))"

#Define error actions.
#$erroractionpreference = "SilentlyContinue"

#Get content from given IP list.
$colComputers = @(get-content $File | Sort -unique)
$SourceCount = $colComputers.Count
    write-output "$Count IP's detected."

#Get DNS Results
$Progress=1
$DNSResults = $colComputers | %{
 Write-Progress -Activity "Creating a usable 'Blocked IP' list ($Progress/$sourcecount)" -PercentComplete ($Progress/$sourceCount*100) -Status "Please stand by"
try {
    ($dnsresult = [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry($_))|out-null
}
catch {
    $dnsresult = "Fail"
}
[PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
    Source=$_.ToUpper()
    HostName=$dnsresult.HostName
    IPAddress=$dnsresult.AddressList[0].ToString()
}
$Progress++
}

$count = ($DNSResults|?{$_ -match $filter}).count

#Open Excel.
$a = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application

#Since we want this script to look like it's being used without excel I set it's visibility to false.
$a.visible = $True

#Disable excel confirmations.
$a.DisplayAlerts = $False

<# 
# set interactive to false so nothing from excel is shown.
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$Excel.ScreenUpdating = $false
$Excel.Visible = $false
$Excel.UserControl = $false
$Excel.Interactive = $false
#>

#Create sheets in Excel.
$b = $a.Workbooks.Add()
$c = $b.Worksheets.Item(1)
$c.Activate() | Out-Null

#Create a Title for the first worksheet and adjust the font
$c.Cells.Item(1,1)= "Blocked IP's $Date"
$c.Cells.Item(1,1).Font.ColorIndex = 55
$c.Cells.Item(1,1).Font.Color = 8210719
$range = $c.Range("a1","e1")
$range.Style = 'Title'
$range.Select()
$range.MergeCells = $true
$range.VerticalAlignment = -4108

$CounterRow = $Count+5
#Define subjects.
$c.Name = "Blocked IP's ($Date)"
$c.Cells.Item(2,1) = "Given IP"
$c.Cells.Item(2,2) = "Resolved DNS"
$c.Cells.Item(2,3) = "Returned IP"
$c.Cells.Item(2,5) = "$Company"
$c.Cells.Item($Count+5,1) = "Created by"
$link = "http://www.$Company"
$link2 = "https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=#########"
$r = $c.Range("E2") 
[void]$c.Hyperlinks.Add($r, $link) 
$r = $c.Range("A$Counterrow") 
[void]$c.Hyperlinks.Add($r, $link)

#Define cell formatting from subjects.
$c.Range("A2:E2").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
$c.Range("A2:E2").font.size = 13
$c.Range("A2:E2").Font.ColorIndex = 1
$c.Range("A2:E2").Font.Bold = $True

#Define html code for Excel save to .htm.
$xlExcelHTML = 44

#Define the usedrange, excluding header and footer rows
$e = $c.Range("A3:E$(2+$Count)")

#Populate data into spreadsheet
$DNSResults | Where{$_ -match $filter} | Sort HostName | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation | Select -Skip 1 | Out-Clipboard
#$c.Cells.Item(3,1).Select()
$c.Paste($e,$false)

ForEach($Cell in $e){
If([String]::IsNullOrWhitespace($Cell.value2)){$Cell.interior.colorindex=6}
}

#Define the usedrange for autofitting.
$d = $c.UsedRange

#Set background color for the IP list.
$E.interior.colorindex = 15

#Define borders here.
$xlOpenXMLWorkbook = 51
$xlAutomatic=-4105
$xlBottom = -4107
$xlCenter = -4108
$xlRight = -4152
$xlContext = -5002
$xlContinuous=1
$xlDiagonalDown=5
$xlDiagonalUp=6
$xlEdgeBottom=9
$xlEdgeLeft=7
$xlEdgeRight=10
$xlEdgeTop=8
$xlInsideHorizontal=12
$xlInsideVertical=11
$xlNone=-4142
$xlThin=2 
$selection = $c.range("A3:C$($DNSResults.Count+2)")
$selection.select() |out-null
$selection.HorizontalAlignment = $xlRight
$selection.VerticalAlignment = $xlBottom
$selection.WrapText = $false
$selection.Orientation = 0
$selection.AddIndent = $false
$selection.IndentLevel = 0
$selection.ShrinkToFit = $false
$selection.ReadingOrder = $xlContext
$selection.MergeCells = $false
$selection.Borders.Item($xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = $xlThin



#Make everything fit in it's cell.
$d.EntireColumn.AutoFit() | Out-Null

#Save the file as .xlsx on every placed IP to ensure the file is not lost due to any reason.
$b.SaveAs("$FileXML")

#Clear screen on every checked IP to remove the 'True' statement.
#cls
#


#Save final result as a .htm file
$b.SaveAs("$FileHTML",$xlExcelHTML)

#Close and quit Excel.
$b.Close()
get-process *Excel* | Stop-Process -force

#Move .txt file to the correct HTML folder.
move-item $file $path2 -Force

#Move .xlsx file to the correct HTML folder.
move-item $filexml $path2 -Force

#Declare XLSX file for mail
$MailXML = "$path2\IP-$Date.xlsx"

#Clear screen, again. (Let's keep things tidy.)
#cls

#Variables for public IP
# I am defining website url in a variable
$url = "http://checkip.dyndns.com" 
# Creating a new .Net Object names a System.Net.Webclient
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
# In this new webdownlader object we are telling $webclient to download the
# url $url 
$IpPublic = $webclient.DownloadString($url)
# Just a simple text manuplation to get the ipadress form downloaded URL
# If you want to know what it contain try to see the variable $IpPublic
$IpPublic2 = $IpPublic.ToString()
$ipPublic3 = $IpPublic2.Split(" ")
$ipPublic4 = $ipPublic3[5]
$ipPublic5 = $ipPublic4.replace("</body>","")
$FinalIPAddress = $ipPublic5.replace("</html>","")
$ipLocal = (Get-WmiObject -class win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter 'ipenabled = "true"').ipaddress[0]

#Variables e-mail.
$From = "Blocked IP <r.van.tour@$Company>"
$To = "IT Dept <r.van.tour@$Company>"
$CC = "Someone <$Company2@$Company"
$Subject = "Blocked IPs for $date ($Count Total)"
#The href should point to the htm file in your iis/apache folder.
$WebLink = $FinalIPAddress+$FileHtmlWeb
$here = "<a href='http://$Weblink'><b>Here</b></a>"
#Define the body of your e-mail, in this case it displays a message and shows the server it is send from with it's local IP.
#A link to the .htm file, how many IP's were blocked and the date of the message.
$Body = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head> <title>Blocked IP's $Date</title></head><header><h1>Blocked IP</h1><p><time pubdate datetime='$date'></time></p></header><br>" 
$body += "<body>Dear <font color=black>$to</font>,<br><br>"
$body += "This is an automated message generated by server: <font color=red><b>$env:COMPUTERNAME, $IPLocal.</b></font><br><br>"
$body += "Click <font color=red><b>$here</b></font> to see the Blocked IP report for $date containing $count IP's.<br>"
$body += "Or see the attachment to open it in Excel.<br></body></html>"


#Clear screen, again. (Let's keep things tidy.)
#cls

#Send output as e-mail.
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
$Username = "##@gmail.com"
$Password = "##"
$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$message.IsBodyHTML = $true
$message.ReplyTo = $From
$message.Sender = $From
$message.subject = $subject
$message.body = $body
$message.to.add($to)
$message.from = $From
$message.attachments.add($MailXML)
$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);
$smtp.EnableSSL = $true
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
$smtp.send($message)

#Create a function to relase Com object at end of script.
function Release-Ref ($ref) { 
([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject( 
[System.__ComObject]$ref) -gt 0) 
[System.GC]::Collect() 
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers() 
                        }

#Release COM Object
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$a) | Out-Null

#Clear screen for the final time. (Let's keep things tidy.)
#cls

#Exit powershell 
exit
```

**Edit:** I found the issue with your script. You didn't update the line where you are copying to the clipboard, you just added in lines later in the script, after the script already pasted to Excel, so the code you added effectively did nothing. I've made a couple of updates to your code (to handle record counts better, and filter correctly), and updated the above script.

**Edit2:** Man this post is getting long. Ok, so to include all entries I've modified a few things. First the ForEach loop that looks up the DNS results, I modified the object creation lines to check if they exist before trying to populate so it stops throwing errors on things that don't have one or both HostName and IP Addresses for DNS Lookups.

```
[PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
    Source=$_.ToUpper()
    HostName=$(if(!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($dnsresult.HostName))){$dnsresult.HostName})
    IPAddress=$(if(!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($dnsresult.AddressList))){$dnsresult.AddressList[0].ToString()})
}
```

Then I split the results into three catagories: With Hostname matching a keyword, with Hostname not matching a keyword, and no Hostname (also change $count wince we are including everything).

```
$DNSWithKeyword = $DNSResults | ?{$_.HostName -match $Filter}
$DNSNoKeyword = $DNSResults | ?{!($_.HostName -match $Filter) -and !([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.HostName))}
$DNSLookupFailed = $DNSResults | ?{([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.HostName))}
#$count = ($DNSResults|?{$_ -match $filter}).count
$count = $SourceCount
```

Then down a ways where used range is defined I added one for each category, and instead of just one Copy/Paste I do three so there are those matching keywords first, sorted by hostname, then no keyword sorted by hostname, and then those that have no hostname. Then I colored each by section, and went back after and colored blank cells yellow again.

```
#Define the usedrange, excluding header and footer rows
$KeyRange = $c.Range("A3:E$(2+$DNSWithKeyword.Count)")
$NoKeyRange = $c.Range("A$(2+$DNSWithKeyword.Count+1):E$(2+$DNSWithKeyword.Count+$DNSNoKeyword.Count)")
$NoDNSRange = $c.Range("A$(2+$DNSWithKeyword.Count+$DNSNoKeyword.Count+1):E$(2+$DNSWithKeyword.Count+$DNSNoKeyword.Count+$DNSLookupFailed.Count)")
$e = $c.Range("A3:E$(2+$Count)")

#Populate data into spreadsheet
$DNSWithKeyword | Sort HostName | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation | Select -Skip 1 | Out-Clipboard
$c.Paste($KeyRange,$false)
$DNSNoKeyword | Sort HostName | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation | Select -Skip 1 | Out-Clipboard
$c.Paste($NoKeyRange,$false)
$DNSLookupFailed | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation | Select -Skip 1 | Out-Clipboard
$c.Paste($NoDNSRange,$false)

#Define the usedrange for autofitting.
$d = $c.UsedRange

#Set background color for the IP list.
$KeyRange.interior.colorindex = 3
$NoKeyRange.interior.colorindex = 15
$NoDNSRange.interior.colorindex = 14

ForEach($Cell in $e){
If([String]::IsNullOrWhitespace($Cell.value2)){$Cell.interior.colorindex=6}
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57575/discussion-between-themadtechnician-and-remy-van-tour).

Comment: You saved my arse buddy, thanks for all your help! You got some mad skills! :D